# Hide legend elements that have value zero in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am trying to write a script that generates stacked barplots showing the percentages of glycoforms on an analysed protein. I am using the "turbo" color scale from Viridis because I need a very wide coverage of colors to be able to distinguish all the glycoforms.

Edit: Here is an example datafile, used to generate 1 single bar:

```
structure(list(Glycoform = c("NaNaF", "NaAF", "NaGnF", "NaMF", 
"NaNa", "NaA", "NaGn", "NaM", "AAF", "AGnF", "AMF", "AA", "AGn", 
"AM/Man4Gn", "Man4A/Man5Gn", "Man5/A", "GnGnXF", "MGnXF", "MMXF", 
"GnGnF", "MGnF", "MMF", "GnGnX", "MGnX", "MMX", "GnGn", "MGn", 
"MM", "Man9", "Man8", "Man7", "Man6", "Man5", "Man4", "Rest"), 
    Raw = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 81.82, 
    5.35, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10.69, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 2.14), Percentage = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 81.82, 5.35, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10.69, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.14), Plant = c("A", "A", "A", "A", 
    "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
    "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
    "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -35L))
```

Because it is imperative that in every plot, a respective glycoform has to have the same color, I order my glycoforms like so:

```
t$Glycoform<-factor(t$Glycoform,levels=c("NaNaF","NaAF","NaGnF","NaMF","NaNa","NaA","NaGn","NaM","AAF","AGnF","AMF","AA","AGn","AM/Man4Gn","Man4A/Man5Gn","Man5/A","GnGnXF","MGnXF","MMXF","GnGnF","MGnF","MMF","GnGnX","MGnX","MMX","GnGn","MGn","MM","Man9","Man8","Man7","Man6","Man5","Man4","Rest"))
```

But because in my raw data, non-found glycoforms have a %-value of 0, they still show up in the legend:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(viridis)
ggplot(t,aes(fill=Glycoform,y=Percentage,x=Plant,group=Glycoform))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",color="white",size=1.2, width=0.8)+
  scale_fill_viridis(option="turbo",discrete="TRUE")+
  geom_text(data=subset(t,Percentage>0),position=position_stack(vjust=0.5),color="white",size=4,aes(label=Glycoform),fontface="bold")+
  guides(fill=guide_legend(ncol=2))
```

[barplot with wrong legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4Raf.png)

When I convert the unused values to NA, the legend is fixed, but the color-assignment is wrong:

```
t[t == 0] <- NA
ggplot(t,aes(fill=Glycoform,y=Percentage,x=Plant,group=Glycoform))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",color="white",size=1.2, width=0.8)+
  scale_fill_viridis(option="turbo",discrete="TRUE")+
  geom_text(data=t,position=position_stack(vjust=0.5),color="white",size=4,aes(label=Glycoform),fontface="bold")+
  guides(fill=guide_legend(ncol=2))
```

[barplot with wrong colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrp5L.png)

I was unable to either lock colors onto factors in Viridis if unused values are set to NA and also unable to hide legend elements of values of zero in the case where I leave them as zeros. I am a R-beginner.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data.

Comment: Thanks, @stefan! I have edited the original post with an examplary dataset which produces the first bar of the three bar example plots that I show. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the categories to show up in the legend via the `breaks` argument of `scale_fill_viridis`, i.e. make a vector of all non-zero categories and pass this vector to the breaks argument.

Using a minimal reproducible example based on the `ggplo2::mpg` dataset.

Just to reproduce your isse the  first plot shows all categories in the legend even the one for which I set `n=0`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(viridis)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)

manu <- sample(unique(mpg$manufacturer), 5)
# make example data
mpg2 <- mpg |> 
  count(drv, manufacturer) |> 
  mutate(n = ifelse(manufacturer %in% manu, n, 0))

ggplot(mpg2 , aes(drv, n, fill = manufacturer)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_viridis(option="turbo",discrete="TRUE")
```

[image]

To drop the zero categories from the legend I pass the vector of none-zero categories to the `breaks` argument which as you can see will not affect the colors assigned to the categories:

```r
ggplot(mpg2 , aes(drv, n, fill = manufacturer)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_viridis(option="turbo",discrete="TRUE", breaks = manu)
```

[image]

**EDIT** And for  your "real" data you could do:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(viridis)
#> Loading required package: viridisLite

non_zero<- unique(t$Glycoform[t$Percentage > 0])

ggplot(t,aes(fill=Glycoform,y=Percentage,x=Plant,group=Glycoform))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",color="white",size=1.2, width=0.8)+
  scale_fill_viridis(option="turbo",discrete="TRUE", breaks = non_zero)+
  geom_text(data=subset(t,Percentage>0),position=position_stack(vjust=0.5),color="white",size=4,aes(label=Glycoform),fontface="bold")+
  guides(fill=guide_legend(ncol=2))
```

[image]

Comment: Haha. Yeah. I just made an edit using your data.

Comment: This completely solves my issue. Thanks so much, you havo no idea how long I've been sitting on this.